# Uniform convergence doesn't preserve improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

Given $f_{n} : [0,  \infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of continuous functions that converge uniformaly to $f$

We know that $f_{n}$ is Riemann integrable any closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b}  f_{n} \ dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx $$

However when the integral is improper
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{\infty}  f_{n} \ dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ \lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b}  f_{n} \neq \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx $$ even though uniform convergence preserves limits?

I've seen a few counterexamples, but I don't understand what property of the improper integral makes this not possible.

Comment: The problem is that $[0,\infty)$ has infinite measure, so uniform convergence (which is convergence in $L^\infty$) does not imply convergence in $L^1$. You may want to look into [Lebesgue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)

Comment: Note that the same phenomenon happens for series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty$. Again, the problem is that the underlying measure is not finite

Comment: You're interchanging two limits and interchanging a limit with an integral.  If the integral converges uniformly for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then you can interchange the limits and proceed

Comment: If it where, then $|\int_X f_n\,d\mu-\int_X f\,d\mu|\leq\|f_n-f\|_\infty \mu(X)$ and uniform (L^\infty) convergence would imply $L^1$ convergence

Comment: I haven't studied measure yet, but will look into it! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb n}$ is a sequence of Riemann-integrable functions from $[0,a]$ into $\mathbb R$ wich converges uniformly to $f\colon[0,a]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$, then, for each $\varepsilon>0$, you have, if $n$ is large enough,$$(\forall x\in[0,a]):\bigl\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon,$$and therefore,$$\left\lvert\int_0^af(x)\,\mathrm dx-\int_0^af_n(x)\,\mathrm dx\right\rvert<\varepsilon a.\tag1$$So, if $n$ is large enought, the numbers $\int_0^af(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and $\int_0^af_n(x)\,\mathrm dx$ are close to each other. But if are integrating over, say $[0,\infty)$, then you don't have $(1)$ and so the integrals $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,\mathrm dx$ give you no information about $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: If the improper integral converges uniformly, then the interchange is permissible.